# How to access the clock time using react-native-reanimated or react-native-redash

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I'm running a `clock` for the animation which is working fine but I want to know `time` also meaning in the middle of the animation I want to check how much time it took and how much time is remaining to complete the animation. Is that possible to know?

```
const runTiming = (clock, timing) => {
const state = {
    finished  : new Value(0),
    position  : new Value(0),
    frameTime : new Value(0),
    time      : new Value(0)
};
const config = {
    toValue  : new Value(1),
    duration : timing,
    easing   : Easing.linear
};

return block([
    cond(not(clockRunning(clock)), set(state.time, 0), timing(clock, state, config)),
    // cond(not(clockRunning(clock)), debug('no running')),

    cond(state.finished, stopClock(clock)),
    state.position
  ]);
};

const SpecialTestTimer = ({ preparationTime, appState, Timing }) => {
const clock = useClock();
const progress = useValue(0);

useCode(
    () => [
        cond(and(!preparationTime, not(clockRunning(clock))), startClock(clock)),
        cond(and(isCompleted, clockRunning(clock)), stopClock(clock)),

        set(progress, runTiming(clock, durationTiming))
    ],
    [ preparationTime ]
);

 return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ProgressTimer {...{ progress }} />
  </View>
  );
 }
```